# If a FabricJS object is moved by code, the mouse selection does not appear to work

Tags: fabricjs

If I move an object by code, when the mouse is used to select the object, the selection seems to select the object based on its *old* position. In the example below, the object can be selected by its old position, and not in its current position.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in FabricJS?

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
});

canvas.add(rect);

var rect_json = rect.toJSON();
rect_json.left += 100;
rect.set(rect_json);
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh2L0xn3/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setCoords` in order to make the control positions recalculate.

Please check this link [When to call setCoords](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/wiki/When-to-call-setCoords).

```
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
});

canvas.add(rect);

rect.set({ left: 300 }).setCoords()
```